# Integrating two SFDC orgs without username and password

Tags: apex, rest-api

I want to integrate two Salesforce orgs through REST API using OAuth. I am able to do this through connected app via consumer key and consumer secret key. However this process requires username and password. 
Is there a way to connect two orgs without username and password?

Comment: Use oAuth with access and refresh tokens. Have a page where a user can authorize and store the tokens in a custom setting.

Comment: Are you worried about needing to *store* the username and password for ongoing connections, or for the initial connection? Once you have a session available, the username and password are irrelevant.